# Getting java array by splitting a string into conditional substrings

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a java string 'str'

```
String str= " 1p   qrn qr2 qst   1a1 4at   qa qb1  st1 sp su";
```

I want to split it to get the following 'parts' array

```
String [] parts={"1p","qrn qr2 qst" ,"1a1 4at" ,"qa qb1" ,"st1 sp su"};
```

Elements of 'parts' start with   char 0-9, a,q,s.

Help me for a suitabe regex such that:

```
String [] parts= str.split(a suitable regex);
```

or any other alternative which can do it.

Comment: "qrn qr2 qst" is supposed to be one part? According to your spec it should be 3, no? - Ahh... got it. Never mind

Comment: Yes, because each word starts with q.

Comment: so it should be String [] parts={"1p","qrn", "qr2", "qst" ,"1a1","4at" ,"qa", "qb1" ,"st1", "sp", "su"};

Comment: FYI, added Java code online demo to my answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
[\daqs][\w ]*?(?=\s{2}|$)
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vO0cD4)

For splitting use this regex:

```
\s{2,}(?=[\daqs])
```

#### [Working Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/gU3rU7)

**Java Code:**

```
String [] parts = str.split("\\s{2,}(?=[\\daqs])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Comment: The output I am getting is:

Comment: The output I am getting is:[ ,    ,    ,    ,   ]                   The code is used as:
String [] parts= str.split("[\\daqs][\\w ]*?(?=\\s{2}|$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));                                                                                         There is some flaw, kindly help to correct it.

Comment: System.out.println( parts.length);                                   Gives 1, when it should be more than 1, kindly confirm the matter.

Comment: Sad that even after providing you fully working code you cannot adapt it. See this working demo: http://ideone.com/OpHYat

Comment: I am happy to see the code fully working on ideone.com. Sorry for unnecessary botheration caused by me. But this code did not work in my netbean, and same happened for another chunk of code. It may be due to some virus. So I am going to check my things and to update your answer. Again sorry for the botheration.

Comment: Java should behave same every where. If you can reproduce the problem on ideone demo code I can investigate.

Comment: I have no doubt in your code. I fully believe you. The fault is only at mine. I am going to reinstall the netbean etc and if needed java so on. Because I do not know why my tools are deceiving me. I have tried again and again, but failed. Surprise is that other code files are giving expected results, but not this. I mean your code is all ok. There is some fault in my tools.

Comment: After resetting the java and netbean on my computer your code has worked well on my computer. Thanks great man.

Answer (score 1):

With your string, this will work:

```
String[] yourArray = subjectString.split("^\\s+|\\s{2,}");
```

See the output at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/cuCdTb).

**How does this work?**

It looks like your tokens are separated by multiple places. This is what we will use to split: `\s{2,}`
In addition, we want to remove any spaces at the beginning of the string, so we add this to the split conditions: `^\s+`

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment instead of answer but unfortunately I can't so I have to just do an answer. What you said doesn't actually work - as if it started with those characters, it would end up as

```
String [] parts={"1p", "qrn", "qr2", "qst" ,"1a1", "4at" ,"qa", "qb1" ,"st1", "sp", "su"};
```

so to answer your actual question,

[0-9aqs]\w+

should work as you want. If that's not what you want, clarify how they are split, because how you split doesn't fit "Elements of 'parts' start with char 0-9, a,q,s."